# Java PriorityQueue Comparator

Tags: java, objetos, comparação

Estou tentando entender o porque o modo nativo do java nao esta efetuando a comparação, não sei onde estou errando.

MAIN

```
//  EXERCICIO PARA COMPARAR DOIS OBJETOS, USANDO CLASSE NATIVA DE COMPARAÇÃO DO JAVA

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FilaComPrioridade<Paciente> fila = new FilaComPrioridade<>();

    // CLASSE ANONIMA DENTRO DO NOSSO PROJETO.
    Queue<Paciente> filaComPrioridade = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Paciente>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Paciente p1, Paciente p2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(p1.getPrioridade()).compareTo(p2.getPrioridade());
        }
    });

    filaComPrioridade.add(new Paciente("A", 2));
    filaComPrioridade.add(new Paciente("B1", 1));
    filaComPrioridade.add(new Paciente("B2", 1));
    filaComPrioridade.add(new Paciente("B3", 1));
    filaComPrioridade.add(new Paciente("B4", 1));
    filaComPrioridade.add(new Paciente("C", 3));

    fila.enfileira(new Paciente("A", 2));
    fila.enfileira(new Paciente("B1", 1));
    fila.enfileira(new Paciente("B2", 1));
    fila.enfileira(new Paciente("B3", 1));
    fila.enfileira(new Paciente("B4", 1));
    fila.enfileira(new Paciente("C", 3));

    System.out.println(filaComPrioridade);
    System.out.println(fila);
}
```

}

Impressão

> [Paciente [nome=B1, prioridade=1], Paciente [nome=B3, prioridade=1],
>   Paciente [nome=B2, prioridade=1], Paciente [nome=A, prioridade=2],
>   Paciente [nome=B4, prioridade=1], Paciente [nome=C, prioridade=3]]
>
> [Paciente [nome=B1, prioridade=1], Paciente [nome=B2, prioridade=1],
>   Paciente [nome=B3, prioridade=1], Paciente [nome=B4, prioridade=1],
>   Paciente [nome=A, prioridade=2], Paciente [nome=C, prioridade=3]]

Classe FilaComPrioridade:

```
package pt.estruturadedados.base.fila;

public class FilaComPrioridade<T> extends Fila<T> {

    @Override
    public void enfileira(T elemento) {

        Comparable<T> chave = (Comparable<T>) elemento;

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.tamanho; i++) {
            if (chave.compareTo(this.elementos[i]) < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        this.adiciona(i, elemento);
    }

}
```

`CompareTo` na Classe Paciente de Forma Manual "NÃO NATIVA" (Segunda Impressão)

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Paciente o) {

    return Integer.valueOf(this.getPrioridade()).compareTo(o.getPrioridade()); //Forma mais elegante de fazer.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Não vou saber entrar muito em detalhes, mas aqui vai:

O método `System.out.println()` usa o método `toString()` da classe AbstractCollection e este, por sua vez, usa um Iterator (que é obtido através do método `iterator()` da própria PriorityQueue). Acontece que o método `iterator()` da classe PriorityQueue não garante a ordem dos elementos na fila.

Documentação do método `iterator()`:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this collection. **There are no
>   guarantees concerning the order in which the elements are returned**
>   (unless this collection is an instance of some class that provides a
>   guarantee).

Todavia, caso você utilize os métodos da própria classe PriorityQueue para manipular os elementos eles serão retirados na ordem correta, de acordo com a prioridade predefinida. Exemplo:

Classe Paciente:

```
public class Paciente implements Comparable<Paciente> {

    private String nome;
    private int prioridade;

    public Paciente(String nome, int prioridade) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.prioridade = prioridade;
    }
```

métodos get e set para os atributos...

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Paciente o) {
        if (this.prioridade > o.getPrioridade()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.prioridade < o.getPrioridade()) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + nome + ", " + prioridade + "]";
    }

}
```

---

Classe DuvidaPriorityQueue:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;

public class DuvidaPriorityQueue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Queue<Paciente> pqPac = new PriorityQueue<>();

        pqPac.add(new Paciente("A", 9));
        pqPac.add(new Paciente("B", 5));
        pqPac.add(new Paciente("C", 8));
        pqPac.add(new Paciente("D", 1));
        pqPac.add(new Paciente("E", 2));

        System.out.println(pqPac);//O que você fez

        System.out.println();

        //O que deveria ter feito:
        while(!pqPac.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(pqPac.poll() + ", ");
        }


    }

}
```

A saída desta última classe será a seguinte:

> [[D, 1], [E, 2], [C, 8], [A, 9], [B, 5]]
>
> [D, 1], [E, 2], [B, 5], [C, 8], [A, 9],

Teste tentando adicionar os elementos em outra ordem. Se você fizer a saída no console usando os métodos da própria classe PriorityQueue como intermediários, a prioridade que estabeleceu será obedecida. Se usar o método `System.out.println()` direto no objeto PriorityQueue que criou, o resultado vai variar.

---

Fonte (não ria):

Comentário e respostas da Ingrid Marçal e do DevDojo nesse vídeo (e os testes que eu fiz para comprová-los):
[[Youtube]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ehjgp084GtI)

Comment: Excelente resposta, aprendi algo novo. É compreensível que a `PriorityQueue` use uma estrutura de *heap* internamente, mas sinceramente acho uma falha de *design* bem grave da API. Seria melhor fazer um *override* do método `iterator()` para retornar itens na ordem correta (deixando claro para o usuário que o tempo de interação não é linear). O que deve ter de gente caindo em pegadinhas do tipo `for (Paciente p : filaComPrioridade)` não está no gibi.